# can i use comma before 'and' when connecting a dependent clause

Tags: punctuation

"The word is of Dutch origin, and is one of many Dutch words used to discuss barriers in the natural landscape."(https://m.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-berm.htm)
i learned that you shouldn't use a comma before 'and' when one of the clauses it’s connecting is a dependent clause. But "is one of many Dutch words used to discuss barriers in the natural landscape" is dependent clause ,so you shouldn't use comma before 'and' in my knowledge.
My question is :why does  this writer use comma? is it grammarly right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example sentence, I would say you actually have two independent clauses. It's just that the second one is elliptical in a slightly nonstandard way:

> The word is of Dutch origin.
>   The word is one of many Dutch words used to discuss barriers in the natural landscape.

Both of these are independent clauses that could stand on their own as single sentences.

They've been combined into a single sentence, in which the repeated use of *the word* has been dropped (but it is assumed to exist):

> The word is of Dutch origin, and *[the word]* is one of many Dutch words used to discuss barriers in the natural landscape.

---

However, the phrasing is a little awkward, and I'd say it's awkward because of the problem you raise.

Rather than dropping the second instance of *the word* altogether, it would be more natural to replace it with a pronoun:

> The word is of Dutch origin, and **it** is one of many Dutch words used to discuss barriers in the natural landscape.